# Changing Logstash log location from console to file

Tags: docker, log4j, logstash

I have installed `logstash` using `docker`. It is running fine. It seems by default in docker installation, log output goes to console. I want that log output should go to file too along with console.

For this I added the below config items to my `logstash log4j.properties` file

```
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName = /usr/share/logstash/logs/logstash.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n
```

After that I restarted docker container hosting logstash using below command

`docker restart logstash`

But logs are not getting written to log file. It is still going to console. What else I am missing . Also , how to identify the console log file
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Restart will remove the change, you need create a custom dockerfile and change the config there

Comment: Is it because I have made changes in logstash.conf and the changes are consistent even after container hosting logstash restart